# GWT+spring+hibernate error creating bean SessionFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate, gwt

I am getting the following error when I call

> ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml")
>   `

```
<bean id="derbyDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:db/analyticsDB;create=true" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="50" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="derbyDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.analytics.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> 
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

`

Changing log4j version to 1.2.15 produces [this exception](http://pastebin.com/H8z4rgLE).

The issue been resolved after I added the following to spring.xml
`<prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>`

Comment: your problem is with sessionFactory bean, some how the bean is not being created and you get the exception. can you provide the codes of your spring.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part here is `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE`.

It seems to be an error with the version of **log4j** / **slf4j** you are using.

You should only use version **1.2.12** or higher of **log4j**, and make sure there is only one version of **log4j** jar in your classpath.

You should also make sure to not use an **slf4j** version lower than **1.5.1**.

Comment: Changed log4j from version 1.2.8 to 1.2.15, which changed the exception and some more description, however the issue was not resolved. Thank you for point the right version of jar.

Comment: Added <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop> to spring.xml and it worked. Thank you